# Syntax error near unexpected token 'fi' in shell script sqlplus

Tags: bash, shell, while-loop

I'm having an issue here when it comes to executing his bash script. Currently, receiving an error saying syntax error near unexpected token 'fi'. 'fi'.

```
 USER_TYPE=$1 #IDENTIFY USER TYPE TYPE1,TYPE2,TYPE3,TYPE4,TYPE5
 USER_NAME=$2
 TARGET_SCHEMA=$3
 TARGET_TABLE=$4
PERMISSION_TYPE=$5
if $USER_TYPE == 'TYPE1';
    then
sqlplus /  <<  E00
CREATE USER ${USER_NAME}
IDENTIFIED BY "default"
DEFAULT TABLESPACE USERS
TEMPORARY TABLESPACE TEMP
ACCOUNT UNLOCK;
ALTER USER ${USER_NAME} DEFAULT ROLE ALL;
GRANT CREATE SESSION TO ${USER_NAME};
GRANT CONNECT TO ${USER_NAME};
exit
E00
cat perm.txt |while read PERMISSION OWNER TABLE USER 
do
sqlplus / as sysdba > /home/o/direct/Passa/output/output.log << E01
GRANT $PERMISSION ON $OWNER.$TABLE TO $USER; 
E01
fi
```

Comment: I will remove the sqlplus and Oracle tags, since this is a shell scripting question ("fi" has nothing to do with Oracle or sqlplus).

Comment: Fix syntax. Please take a look: http://www.shellcheck.net/

Answer (score 2):

You're missing the `done` keyword for the `while` loop.

```
cat perm.txt |while read PERMISSION OWNER TABLE USER 
do
sqlplus / as sysdba > /home/o/direct/Passa/output/output.log << E01
GRANT $PERMISSION ON $OWNER.$TABLE TO $USER; 
E01
done
fi
```

BTW, this is a [UUOC](http://catb.org/jargon/html/U/UUOC.html). You can just use input redirection

```
while read PERMISSION OWNER TABLE USER 
do
sqlplus / as sysdba > /home/o/direct/Passa/output/output.log << E01
GRANT $PERMISSION ON $OWNER.$TABLE TO $USER; 
E01
done < perm.txt
```

Comment: Lol wow. Thanks so much Barmar. I'll check it out when I get back to my desk.